# How to query Mongoose using drop down menu values that sort through data model?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, drop-down-menu, mongoose

Using mongoimport, I added a csv file that contains 100,000 rows of data to my node application with the help of Mongoose. On my views page, I'm able to access all 100,000 rows and display each piece of information correctly, however the purpose of my app is to allow the user to select parameters on that data and to return only the specific rows of that csv file that meet that criteria. For example, my data is as follows:

Header: Name, State, Degree
 Row 1: Gary, IN, Undergraduate
 Row 2: Carl, FL, PhD
 Row 3: Tina, WI, Masters
 Row 4: Matt, FL, Masters

My select options look like this:

```
<div class="select_menu">
  <label>Select State</label>
  <select name="select_state" id="select_state">
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisonsin</option>
    <option value="etc">ETC</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select Degree</label>
  <select name="select_degree" id="select_degree">
    <option value="PhD">PhD only</option>
    <option value="Masters">PhD and Masters</option>
    <option value="Undergraduate">PhD, Masters, and Undergraduate</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This would be my query parameters:

```
var selectState = document.getElementByID('select_state')
var selectDegree = document.getElementByID('select_degree')

var query = Data.find({ 

STATE: selectState.value, 
DEGREE: selectDegree.value

}).limit(10);
```

Data (Entire CSV file) is pushed to the data.ejs views page through the data.controller which is:

```
const Data = require('../models/data');


module.exports = {
  showDatas: showDatas
}

function showDatas(req, res) {
  Data.find({}, (err, datas) => {
    console.log(datas[0]);
    res.render('pages/data', {datas: datas});
  });
}
```

I'm just lost as to how to apply that above query to the data model once it has been passed to the views page. I know that I can use jQuery and use an onclick function on a "Submit" button next to the select drop downs, but where do I place the actual function? Totally lost, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const Data = require('../models/data');


module.exports = {
    showDatas: showDatas
}


function showDatas(req, res) {

    //query will catch the params url after ? 
    //params will catch the body params? 

    var queryJson={};

    if(req.query.selectState){
        queryJson.STATE=req.query.selectState;
    }


    if(req.query.selectDegree){
        queryJson.DEGREE=req.query.selectDegree;
    }

    Data.find(queryJson, (err, datas) => {
        console.log(datas[0]);
        res.render('pages/data', {datas: datas});
    });
}
```

**Reload your page when select box chnaged and append params to request url**